# javascript for loop does not work with my button addEventListener click event

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, addeventlistener

I would like to use some codes to listen the click event in some buttons and produce some random strings to a textarea with the use of output_random function, this codes work like a charm:

```
buttons[0].addEventListener("click", function () { output_random(allTags[0], ranNums[0], outputs[0]) });
buttons[1].addEventListener("click", function () { output_random(allTags[1], ranNums[1], outputs[1]) });
buttons[2].addEventListener("click", function () { output_random(allTags[2], ranNums[2], outputs[2]) });
buttons[3].addEventListener("click", function () { output_random(allTags[3], ranNums[3], outputs[3]) });
```

but since I am learning Javascript and I thought this kind of codes is not beautiful and would like to make it look like this:

```
   for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
      buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; i++) {
        output_random(allTags[j], ranNums[j], outputs[j])
        };
    
      });
    }
```

But unfortunately it does not work at all, the output is undefined. Can anyone help me with this? I can't quite understand the for loop in this example.
Thank you

Comment: There's no good reason why you still want to use `var` instead of `let` and `const`

Comment: See the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), `i` and `j` don't have the values when the click occurs that you're expecting. In any vaguely modern environment you can use `let` instead and get the result you want (or I'd use a `for-of` loop instead). If you have to support IE11, you'll need to use one of the other solutions (or write modern code and transpile for IE11). Even though IE11 has `let`, it doesn't handle `let` correctly in `for` loops.

Comment: Also, you have a typo: You're incrementing `i` in the inner loop. You probably meant to increment `j` instead. (Which is another great reason to prefer `for-of` to loop arrays.)

Comment: @Andreas, no, I just learn javascript so I can't quite understand the scenario of var & let.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, thank you for pointing my typo, but fixing that that does not produce what I want. But change the var to let have really make my earlier code work. I learned my good lesson with using var instead of let. 'for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function () {

    output_random(allTags[i], ranNums[i], outputs[i])
  });

};'

Comment: Then try to get a tutorial that's already using `let` and `const`. `var` is just legacy stuff with many quirks like its unusual function scope (`let` and `const` have both block scope)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this which should work fine.

```
function myFunction(i)
{
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () { output_random(allTags[i], ranNums[i], outputs[i]) });
}

for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  myFunction(i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you for spotting my typo, but the result of fixing the typo of i++ is not i want. But your suggested codes work like a charm. Thank you again.

Comment: sure thats ok, please vote my answer up and accept it if it works for you. Thanks :)